# Scale up consumers in Kafka across machines/processes

Tags: apache-kafka

If I want to scale up my consumers to a specific topic by spinning up new machines/processes running my consumer code, is it as simple as having the consumers (in all the machines/processes) use the same consumer group id? And Kafka will handle all the coordination?

(Assuming there are more partitions in the topic than consumers)

Just want to confirm my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's that simple !

When consumers join or leaves a consumer group, they automatically (de)register themselves on Zookeeper, which in turn triggers a process that redistribute the load inside the new consumer pool.